# Limiting choices in foreign key dropdown in Django using Generic Views ( CreateView )

Tags: python, django

I've two models:

First one:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    a_title = models.CharField("A title", max_length=500)
```

Second one:

```
class B(models.Model):
    b_a = models.ForeignKey(A, verbose_name=('A'), unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b_details = models.TextField()
```

Now, I'm using CreateView to create form for Value filling :

```
class B_Create(CreateView):
    model = B
    fields = ['b_a','b_details']
```

Then using this to render these field in templates.

Now, my problem is, while giving the field **b_a** ( which is the dropdown ), it list downs all the values of model A, but the need is to list only the values of **model A** which belongs to the particular logged in user, in the dropdown.

I've seen all the answers, but still not able to solve the problem.
The things I've tried:

- **limit_choices_to** in models : Not able to pass the value of A in the limit_choices
- **form_valid** : Don't have the model A in the CreateView, as only B is reffered model in B_Create
- **passing primary key of A in templates via url** : Then there is no instance of A in the template so can't access. Also, don't want to handle it in templates.

I'm new to Django and still learning, so don't know to override admin form.

Please suggest the implemented way, if possible to the problem. I've researched and tried most of the similar questions with no result for my particular problem. I feel like, this is a dumb question to ask, but I'm stuck here, so need help.

Thanks..

(Please feel free to suggest corrections.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have access to `self.request.user` in the `form_valid` of the view. But in order to limit the choices in the form you have to customize the form before it is served initially. You best override the view's [`get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form) and set the form field's [`queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset):

```
class B_Create(CreateView):
    model = B
    fields = ['b_a','b_details']

    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(B_Create, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)
        form.fields['b_a'].queryset = self.request.user.a_set.all()
        # form.fields['b_a'].queryset = A.objects.filter(a_user=self.request.user) 
        return form
```

Generally, there are three places where you can influence the choices of a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

1. If the choices need no runtime knowledge of your data, user, or form instance, and are the same in every context where a modelform might be used, you can set `limit_choices_to` on the `ForeignKey` field itself; as module level code, this is evaluated once at module import time. The according query will be built and executed every time a form is rendered.
2. If the choices need no runtime knowledge, but might be different in different forms, you can use custom `ModelForms` and set the `queryset` in the field definition of the respective form field.
3. If the queryset needs any runtime information, you can either override the `__init__` of a custom form and pass it any information it needs to set the field's queryset or you just modify the queryset on the form after it is created which often is a quicker fix and django's default views provide nice hooks to do that (see the code above).

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for the quick response and awesome solution. I'll vote up when i'll get 15 reps.

Answer (score 3):

The @schwobaseggl answer is excellent.

Here is a Python 3 version. I needed to limit the projects dropdown input based on the logged-in user.

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'brand/product-create.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class=None)
        form.fields['project'].queryset = form.fields['project'].queryset.filter(owner_id=self.request.user.id)
        return form
```